# UISplitView crashing after selecting a row

Tags: xcode, ipad, ios5, uisplitviewcontroller

I have a `UISPlitViewController`, I have a `UITableView` in my rootView and have a detailView, on select of second row in my rootView, what i am trying to do is: remove the `UISplitViewController` and add a new `UISplitViewController` (based on my requirement), so in the portrait mode when i select second row from the popOver, the application crashing? (but works well in landscape mode).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm 100% sure I can answer the question, but it would help if you posted some code. What code are you using now that is working for landscape but crashes in portrait?

(I would've written this in a comment, but I need 50 rep for that).

Answer (score 0):

```
    [splitViewController.view removeFromSuperview];

    splitViewController = [[UISplitViewController alloc] init];

    rootObj  = [[HotelsRootViewController alloc] init];        
    mapObj = [[mapViewController alloc] init];
    rootObj.mapObj = mapObj;

    UINavigationController *rootNav=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:rootObj];
    UINavigationController *detailNav=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:mapObj];
    [mapObj release];

    splitViewController.viewControllers=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:rootNav,detailNav,nil];
    splitViewController.delegate=mapObj;
    [window addSubview:splitViewController.view];
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

This is what i do on selection of the second row in my rootViewController, im removing the entire splitView and adding a new SplitView (based on my requirement), but if im in landscape mode, the app doesnt crash, when i turn my iPad in Potrait mode, when i click the button in the toolbar and in the popOver when i select the same second row in the rootView, the app is crashing.....hope u understood now....